# Linq Select not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Board` which contains a list of `OverallPartyResults`.

`OverallPartyResults` has a property `PartyName` which should be distinct in the list.

> I am trying to write logic for adding `OverallPartyResults` to the list Which should only add a new `OverallPartyResults` if the board doesn't contain an `OverallPartyResults` with the same code.

The linq expression I am writing is:

```
if (!Board.Select(i => i.PartyCode).Contains(party.PartyCode))
{
      var newPartyResult = new OverallPartyResults()
      {
             PartyCode = party.PartyCode.Trim(),
             NumberOfSeats = seatNumber 

      };
      Board.Add(newPartyResult);
}
```

The expression is wrong as I am getting `OverallPartyResults` in the list with the same code - can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this `Board.Select(i => i.PartyName).ToList().Contains(party.PartyCode)` ?

Comment: Try .Contains(party.PartyCode.Trim()) Maybe you are fooled by the whitespaces

Comment: You are not using the result of the `Select` operator, what really do you expect?

Comment: @IvanStoev I am relatively new to Linq, had you thought it might be more helpful to give me an alternative or explain where I might be going wrong?

Comment: You can at least shorten this to: `if (!Board.Any(i => i.PartyCode == party.PartyCode))`  But overall I think you're going to have to examine these runtime values to see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, you use the `Select` just to check if `Board` contains an item with that `party.PartyCode`. The question is what is the `party` variable and where it comes from. Also as other mentioned, the check is not consistent with the add - missing `Trim`. Anyway, looks like your problem is not with `Select` - the post title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `Trim()` is the one to blame. If you have spaces in the beginning or the end of `PartyCode` then You will get duplicate `PartyCode`s

Rewrite it like this:

```
if (!Board.Any(i => i.PartyCode == party.PartyCode.Trim()))
{
      var newPartyResult = new OverallPartyResults()
      {
             PartyCode = party.PartyCode.Trim(),
             NumberOfSeats = seatNumber 

      };
      Board.Add(newPartyResult);
}
```

Use `Any()` instead of `Select(...).Contains()`. You are retrieving all `PartyCodes` from database (if you are using LINQ to BD). `Any` translates to `WHERE EXISTS` witch is much better (Performance wise).